# Can I capture tests from test.each tagged template literals for another context?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, template-literals, tagged-templates

Hundreds of automated tests to verify calculations, written using Jest's `jest.each` feature, need to be presented to decision-makers in another, more legible form.  A typical test suite would start something like this (example numbers):

```
describe('Drug 1', () => {
test.each`
weight  | vial   | expectedMg | expectedMl  | clinicalCaseNumber
${140}  | ${250} | ${10}      | ${2}        | ${'I13'}
${140}  | ${500} | ${10}      | ${1}        | ${'I14'}
```

I would like to access the test data in my `*.test.js` files from the React app being tested so that permissioned users can review the automated tests being run.

I had hoped to do something like this:

```
export const DRUGS = {};
DRUGS['Drug 1'] = `
    weight  | vial   | expectedMg | expectedMl  | clinicalCaseNumber
    ${140}  | ${250} | ${10}      | ${2}        | ${'I13'}
    ${140}  | ${500} | ${10}      | ${1}        | ${'I14'}
```

And then use the template literals both with `test.each` here and within the application.  However, this doesn't seem to be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate script as an entry point

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dump": "node scripts/dump.js",
    "posttest": "npm run dump"
  }
}
```

You can reuse [jest-each](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-each) to define a global test function and create the desired output

**`scripts/dump.js`**

```
const bindEach = require('jest-each').bind;
const glob = require('glob');

global.describe = (desc, cb) => {
  console.log(desc);
  cb();
};

const test = (desc, cb) => {
  console.log(desc);
};

test.each = bindEach(test);

global.test = test;

glob.sync('**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)').forEach((testFile) => {
  require(`./${testFile}`);
});
```

Comment: I like this solution but had trouble getting it to work since I use React `import` statements.  Less elegant, but within a test file I was able to wrap my tests in a `testRun` function, follow the initial run by executing a `redefine` function following your example above, and then repeat `testRun` to convert my tests to data and save them as JSON.

Comment: @ed94133 to make the imports work you'll need Babel